# Hibernate error "database is locked". How do i correctly close session?

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite, session

In my application I open session, create criteria but dont close it. Then in other method I open session again, update object and receive `database is locked` on `tr.commit()`.

If I put `session.close()` in first instance I receive

> could not initialize proxy - no Session.

How do I close and open sessions correctly? Or do I need to copy proxy objects to those created by me and then `close()`?

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tr=session.beginTransaction();

        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(MyDocument.class);
        criteria.add(Expression.like("isMainDoc", 1));

        List docs = criteria.list();

        tr.commit();
        session.close();
```

I am a complete begginer. i use sqlite. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate Session is generally tied to a thread.

So, perhaps you should restructure your code to get a session at the beginning of your processing (e.g. in ServletFilter instance of a web-app).

And then in each method, you can use the same session object, to start a new transaction (and then of course, end the transaction also.

```
public void doWork(){
  Transaction tx = null;
   try{
     tx = session.beginTransaction();  
   }catch(){
   } finally {
     // if tx != null then.. close transaction, or rollback?
   }
}
```

EDIT:  And then ofcouse, close the session when the processing is done (in web-app, that could be also in the same ServletFilter) 
Google:  "Open Session In View" pattern.

Comment: thank you for answer. bare with me. Im making desktop application. Could you explain further how to get session. Do i make session at initialization of main form? How do i use it in other forms?

Comment: I think in Desktop Applications, a new thread is started for each event, such as button click.

So perhaps the new session should be opened at the button click.

1. The sessionFactory should be created when the Application is loaded.

2. The session should be created (using same API that you are using)  when a new Thread is being started.

So maybe you need to create a session in the EventHandlers.

Comment: thank you for explanation.How do retrieve sessionfactory and session. Do i make them static? im a beginner in this.

Comment: HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory() works fine. Do i need to call this once?

Comment: yes, call HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()  only once when the application starts.  You probably a class that has the responsibility of starting the application. In Java, that will be the class that has method: public static void main(String[] args).  So, in that class, this should get called exactly once: , call HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()

Comment: this sessionFactory that is obtained, can then be made "static", and made use of in each Event Handler to open a new session when Event handling starts.

Comment: where do i close session. please explain to me.

Comment: Session should be closed at the end of the thread. So if you are using Event Handler, then it would be the last call in the EventHandler. Preferably in the 'finally' block if you have a try-catch-finally.

Comment: if close session i get could not initialize proxy - no Session. if i dont i get database is locked. maybe its db specific i use sqlite.

Comment: are any other operations on the session successful? Such as starting a transaction ?

Comment: ok. i made SessionFactory and session from it static and initialize them at the start of main frame. It seams to work. I cant thank you enough for your help and explanations.

Answer (score 2):

### Cause

You might be getting the error when you are trying to access properties of the `MyDocument` class instances returned by the query.

Hibernate is **lazy** by default. It returns you a `proxy` for an object instead of hitting the database whenever a reference property is accessed. This behavior **can be overwritten** whenever required.
Always remember that could not initialize proxy - no Session is recieved when the code tries to access a `proxy` properties (by hitting the database) and finds that the session is not available ( Session is needed as Hibernate accesses database using this interface)

### Solution

Make sure that your session is open whenever Hibernate tries to load object which have not been loaded yet. How do you do that?

(In simple words) There are two schools of thoughts in Hibernate:

1. Fetch all the data  that you might access before you close the Session OR
2. keep the Session open for the entire duration of time you work on the objects.

I would like you brush up topics such as the unit of work in Hibernate. Hibernate provides a wonderful interface to define boundaries on database access. Data must be accessed (read/written) between these boundaries. [Check Here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-misc-properties)

`hibernate.current_session_context_class` in the hibernate configuration which can take the values jta | thread | managed | custom.Class. This variable defines the unit of work for your `Session`.

Last but most importantly try using [Contextual Sessions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/architecture.html#architecture-current-session)  (you must have come across `.getCurrentSession()`
which helps you to get the *same session which is open everytime anywhere in your code*. Hibernate handles everything behind the scenes.

*Hope this answer serves as a guide for you for taking the correct path in using Hibernate rather than just solving this particular problem.*

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps when you are using [hibernate transactions](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/SessionsAndTransactions) Read the API [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html).

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

//Or any other operation.
session.save(a);

tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. What if just create criteria from session. i dont have a. what do i save?

Comment: **could not initialize proxy - no Session** can be because of some other reason also. So verify if the location you are getting the error. Your new code seems to be fine.

Comment: i use List docs in populating table with data i got from criteria, could not initialize proxy - no Session in constructor of a table.